# Website porting. Traffic fall in SEO due to image search

Tags: seo, google-search, ranking, google-image-search, image-search

I ported a website on wordpress.com to my own server. The site had pretty good traffic and we had done a fair amount of work to ensure proper transitioning but  we missed one aspect in redirecting traffic that came via image search.

The original website had some of its SEO traffic via Google Image Search. 
Here’s one of the original URL: https://myrecipecollections.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/rasgulla1.jpg 
When we migrated to the new platform we didn’t have control over the image URLs hosted by Wordpress and ended up with new URLs at http://www.cucumbertown.com/up/media/4Bq07AvNSB6Djl42D8ZNFw/image.1024x1024.jpg

Rasgulla.jpg had very high image traffic rank and the old Wordpress cdn URL still shows up in search. Is there a way I can migrate traffic from the old cdn url to the new one?

**Edit:** Here’s the post for reference: http://www.mareenasrecipecollections.com/rasgullarosogolla-cottage-cheese-balls-in-recipe-dish

Comment: Do you control the filenames of your images on cucumbertown? + Have you redirected the URLs from wordpress to your new site? + Do you still have access to your wordpress account and domain name?

Comment: Yes, I control the filenames of the images on Cucumbertown. 2. I have redirected the posts from wordpress to the new site but the images that were hosted on wordpress cannot be redirected. I don’t have control over those. 3. Yes, I have access to the wordpress accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a 301 redirect command added to the "wordpress.com" web server.

The basic free service doesn't provide this capability.

https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/is-there-a-301-redirects-manager?replies=2#post-2356582

None of the non-Enterprise subscriptions support adding your own plugin

https://en.support.wordpress.com/plugins/

There are 2 possible methods available if you are willing to spend some/lots of money.

1
They sell a redirect service here
https://store.wordpress.com/premium-upgrades/redirect/
There is very limited technical details on how it works in practise so I'd email them and ask if it supports your specific circumstance before purchase.

2
Buy an expensive enterprise subscription to permit use of 3rd party plugins
and get a specialist plugin such as the following ...

https://vip.wordpress.com/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/

Again, be sure to email them first to verify that it will work with images redirects in your specific circumstances.

Another option to consider is to delete your wordpress.com content as soon as practical so that google has no choice but to index and rank your new site. There will be a delay of course, but if your original site content was good enough to rank well and attract traffic, your new site should as well.